# Performance metric for Unsupervised LSTM Anomaly Detection model

Tags: time-series, model-evaluation, lstm, anomaly-detection

I am working on an unsupervised time-series anomaly detection project.

My data consists of 10 variables with some various degrees of correlation between them and around 50 values for each variable. So the dataframe/matrix is of size: 50x10

The model I am using is a single layer univariable LSTM with an architecture I can share if required. The activation function is `ReLU`, optimizer `adam` and `mae` as metrics. I say univariable because at the moment, I am training each model for each variable itself, without taking into consideration the other ones. So I'm building 10 different models, one for each variable.

The anomaly detection right now is made by training the model and making it reconstruct the time series, and measuring the `squared distance` for each point, standarizing the `mse` values and then simply flagging as anomaly those points where this `squared distance` is above a user defined threshold, or above a certain percentile of the `squared distance` values.

The problem I am facing is I can't seem to find a proper way to analyze/evaluate the performance of my model, becuase if I try to minimize the `mse` it doesn't make sense to me, because this would cause the model to (in an extreme case) overfit and match exactly the true values, hence there will be no anomalies. On the other hand, if I just plot a straight line with the mean then any seasonal trend will not get correctly identified hence anomalies will be flagged incorrectly. Being the model unsupervised, there is obviously no accuracy metric to try and fit our model.

Is there a metric or way of evaluating the performance of an unsupervised anomaly detection model without incurring in problems mentioned above?

Here is an output of model fitted for two variables. Is there metric for performance which I can use to compare models and have an objective conclusion on whether a model is performing better than another one?

[image]

*You see the x-aixs going over 50, because I replicated the original matrix to provide more data to the LSTM-model hoping it would generalize a bit better

Comment: you might want to diff the inputs and cumulative sum the outputs for TS handling in general.  You might want to look at Mahalanobis distance given the training distro.  You might want to think about the GEV distribution on each tail, and think about what makes an outlier in a Shewhart sense.  Good luck.  Re-training with the same data isn't necessarily informative, you might want to perturb with slight noise using a generator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Most of these xoncepts are unknown to me so I'll make sure to look them up

Comment: If you give sample/toy data, I can give you toy code for them.  Sometimes it takes a little while to complete the answer, but it would give you something to get started.  Rob Hyndman has a free stats textbook out that covers a lot of these.